# Replace everything before the last '/' that contains a special website in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I have a table with logo column, it contains urls to logos of companies from different websites. I have parsed logos from a website that has the greatest number of logos and now can't update urls to my local adress.

For example, a URL is:

```
http://logo-website.com/77/13/20/company-logo.png
```

I want to replace everything before the last / and add `images/logo/`
Eventually, it should look: `images/logo/company-logo.png`.

The update should be applied only to urls that contain `'logo-website.com'`

This is my example, it seems to me I managed to get only %logo-website% rows but can't evrything replace before last '/'

```
UPDATE `companies` 
SET `Logo` = 'images/logo/' + SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Logo`, '//', 1)
WHERE name LIKE '%logo-website%'
```

Comment: If you've spent time on this then you surely have an attempt you can include in your question.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **`CONCAT()`** and **`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`** functions:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET url = CONCAT('images/logo/', SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', -1))
WHERE url LIKE '%logo-website.com%'
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: Thanks, that helped but if it still has -1 vote I will remove it later